# Is there a hit list or a specific way that Freddy goes about how he kills people?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, friday-the-13th, freddy-vs-jason

I watched **Freddy vs Jason** (2003) and I am a bit confused about how Freddy goes about how he makes his kills:

He makes his kills when his victim falls asleep, he is basically a living nightmare (he kills you when you dream and is in your dream).

Family has told me that when people fall asleep is when he attacks you, but one scene I remember seeing is at the out-in-the-middle-of-the-bush party where Jason attacks.

One teenage girl decides to go for a smoke out in the bush (worst possible choice) and at some point, she comes across Freddy in her dream in some sort of powerplant. Freddy doesn't kill her, but he comes close...Jason is the one who ends up killing her while she is asleep.

So when she is spotted laying on the ground asleep (obviously struggling against Freddy), Jason stabs her repeatedly as seen in the clip below:

**At what point and how did she just fall asleep?**

---

Another kill was with that other teenage guy who scared the Protagonist at the school saying about Freddy.

The death was that he was in a study room where he was studying about Freddy as seen below:

---

Another near death was with the Protagonist when she was in a meeting with her friends, she ends up pulling Freddy's ear off in brings it into reality after her friends woke her up.

---

Freddy tries to kill Jason in the Police Station by taking over the body of a teenage guy, who is taken over control of his body by a slug like creature that breathes smoke into the guy's face. He tried to kill Jason (Freddy did) by stabbing Jason with two syringes with tranquiliser fluid in them. But Jason kills the boy by slicing him in half with his machete.

Freddy finally kills someone's mother which triggers the protagonist to negotiate with Jason to kill Freddy. The battle:

I could be wrong about that clip.

---

What I want to know is:

**How does Freddy target his victims when half the town would be asleep, how he sends his victims to sleep and does he have a kill list at all that makes him decide who he kills or at least try to?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wiki and the fandom wiki are both slightly vague, but they do give enough details to build a working hypothesis.

During the backstory revealed through the series of films, Freddy was raised by an abusive alcoholic, whom he eventually killed with no repercussions. He later married, fathered a daughter and lived on Elm Street, where he murdered 20 children, many of them children of the kids that had bullied him in school.

Due to irregularities in the arrest, he was released, and enraged parents cornered and burned him. Before he died, he was approached by Dream Demons and offered the chance to become one.

None of the articles that I could find specified why he selected the original victims in *Nightmare on Elm Street*, however it can be presumed that they had some connection to his original house. Later details show that he had a preference for selecting victims from the children of people that had been part of the mob that killed him when he was actually alive.

After that, it is revealed that he cannot return unless people remember him and are afraid of him, so it can be further intuited that his victim selection has to be people that fulfill that condition. He does, however, also attempt to get to his daughter again to try and spread influence beyond Springwood.

So, **TL;DR** - He selects his victims from those that he has a personal grudge against, or that know of him *and* are afraid of him *and* live in Springwood.

Most material gleaned from the [wikia](http://nightmareonelmstreet.wikia.com/wiki/Freddy_Krueger) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddy_Krueger) entries for Freddy Krueger.